# Is it possible to do non-disk-shaped clones in lightroom

Tags: lightroom, post-processing

Using spot removal with 100 opacity, one can "clone" little disks out of troubled images.

In a recent shot, I have a long thin line that needs cloned out. Doing this with Photoshop would be easy, but doing this using the remove spot in light room would be super tedious.

> Is it possible to do this completely in light room without making a ton of little disks?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like power lines? I'd love a feature that could do that!

Comment: In this case a cable to a dock :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, what you're describing is not currently possible with the feature set in Adobe Lightroom 3.  The only cloning-type tool is the spot removal tool, which as you note, is a round shape.  One can change the size of the tool but it's always a circle.

While Lightroom can (and does) handle a bulk of many photographers' editing functions, cloning is one of the the reasons why I'll pull an image into Photoshop.

Comment: I'd +10 this if I could. spot on correct answer. (Sadly.)

Comment: "spot" on! Haha I get it! ;) but ya, +1. Big sigh. :/